# Receiving no refresh_token for google oauth

Tags: google-oauth

We are using the following OAuth login URL for getting an access token from our users:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=14e8d9b8-49c0-498f-b896-02965904737c&client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect URL}&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbusiness.manage+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&access_type=offline
```

This is working fine for most of our users, but for one specific user of ours, we can't get a refresh token.

AFAIK, omitting the access_type=offline query param is a likely case for not receiving a refreshToken, but in our case, we do include it in the URL.
Also verified that the oauth flow is working correctly for others.

We did ask the user to remove our application from their google settings's third-party connections page, but the issue persists after that as well.

**Edit**:

Our code for getting the refreshToken (we are using Spring RestTemplate):

```java
final HashMap<String, String> request = new HashMap<>();
request.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
request.put("code", authorizationCode);
request.put("client_id", "{clientId}");
request.put("client_secret", "{clientSecret}");
request.put("redirect_uri", "{callbackUrl}");
var response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", request, byte[].class);
```

Comment: Can I see the code you are using to get the refresh token?   Also what programming language are you using?  Is this a web client?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo edited the question to contain the code
We are using Java (but not the google library, so we can generalize this flow across multiple networks)

Comment: I think you should watch this.  Thats not how it should be formatted [Understanding oauth2 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `prompt=consent` to the OAuth login URL enforced a full reauth, cleaning out the previous configuration from the user's account settings - and resulting in us receiving the refresh_token as expected.